# Constructor Arguments for verification on Etherscan

Tags: contract-development, etherscan, constructor

I want to verify a contract on Etherscan.io, but I am not able to find the correct Constructor Arguments.

I tried everything which is explained on StackExchange, but cannot get it to verify...

using openjeppelin, contract code is below

---

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.9.2/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.9.2/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20Burnable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.9.2/token/ERC20/extensions/draft-ERC20Permit.sol";

contract Happycat is ERC20, ERC20Burnable, ERC20Permit {
    constructor() ERC20("Happycat", "Hcat") ERC20Permit("Happycat") {
        _mint(msg.sender, 100000000000000 * 10 ** decimals());
    }
}
```

---

The contract address is 0xB8e0ddC1db55EAFf61D65BDC483Ff8e2aB26869A

I used compiler v. 0.8.9, NO optimization,
Json file option and single file option

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Well the code doesn't have any constructor arguments.